# Allow scrolling of overflown text with ellipsis - Cordova application

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I am struggling to find a solution to allow text in my hybrid mobile application to be scrolled by the user, but have ellipses displayed at the end of the visible text.

I have tried the solution marked as correct in [text-overflow ellipsis when scrolled is not showing overflown content in Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494361/text-overflow-ellipsis-when-scrolled-is-not-showing-overflown-content-in-chrome), which has not worked in my case.

I have also tried using `touchstart` and `touchend` events to modify the `text-overflow` property during these events, but this seems to have no effect and the text is still truncated when scrolled, as seen below.

Initial text

[image: Initial text]

Scrolled text

[image: Scrolled text]

Below is my HTML, CSS and JQuery

```
<div class="col-xs-10 text-center">
     <p class="profile-sport">This is sample text to see how long the line extends for.</p>
</div>

.profile-sport, .profile-country {
line-height: 50px;
color: #888787;
overflow: scroll;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

.profile-sport::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none;
}

$('.profile-sport').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $('.profile-sport').css('text-overflow', 'ellipsis');
}).bind('touchend', function(){
    $('.profile-sport').css('text-overflow', 'visible');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This link could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/27507784/8265811